# o365 iMAP "Sent to mail recipient" while outlook closed

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

I'm having an issue when using the "send to mail" feature in windows.

[image]

When using this option and outlook is not open it will open the send window like normal but after clicking send this will result outlook into going into "Outlook is closing" mode and jamming with the only way on fixing this is killing the outlook process and re opening, the email does also not send unti reopening outlook.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem that has only recently occurred? And will it be jammed every time?
According to my tests, When using this option and outlook is not open,after clicking send button,outlook will going into "Outlook is closing" for a while and then when you open the outlook program, the email will be automatically sent out.

If you mean that the message will be only send out when reopening outlook, I'm afraid that it is normal.

If you mean that you need to killing the outlook process when jamming, please check the method mentioned in [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0e6b550e-3bf5-4029-92b4-efb7a92954ed/appcrash-when-sent-to-mail-recipient?forum=outlook) to see if it works.